Fixed-Simplex Exercise. How to Show Induced Map on Homology is the Identity?
Let $K$ be a finite simplicial complex which is combinatorially equivalent to $S^{2n}$, where $n\geq 1$. Let $f:K\to K$ be a simplicial mapping satisfying $f^m=\text{id}_K$, where $m>1$. The exercise is to show that if $m$ is odd, then $f$ fixes a simplex. We always consider homology vector spaces over a fixed field, $\mathbb{F}$.

To fix notation, let $H_*(\cdot)$ be the homology functor and define $H_k(f)$ as the linear map induced on the $k$th homology group by $f$. Also let $\chi(\cdot)$ be the Euler characteristic and $\lambda(\cdot)$ be the Lefschetz number of a simplicial map.
As $K\sim S^{2n}$, $H_*(K)=H_*(S^{2n})$. Therefore, $\chi(K)=\chi(S^{2n})=2$.
As $H_*(K)=H_*(S^{2n})$ and because $$H_k(S^{2n})=\begin{cases} \mathbb{F} & \text{ if } r=0,2n \\
0 & \text{ o/w}\end{cases}$$ the linear maps $H_k(f)$ are trivially zero maps for all $k\neq 0,2n$ and are scalar multiplication for $k=0,2n$ as linear maps between $1$ dimensional spaces. So, there are $\alpha_0,\alpha_{2n}\in \mathbb{F}$ such that $$\begin{align*} [H_0(f)](x) &= \alpha_0 x \\
[H_{2n}(f)](y) &= \alpha_{2n} y  \end{align*}$$ By functoriality, $H_k(f^m)=H_k(f)^m$. Thus, we can iterate to get $$\begin{align*} [H_0(f^m)](x) &= \alpha_0^m x \\
[H_{2n}(f^m)](y) &= \alpha_{2n}^m y  \end{align*}$$ Because, $f^m=\text{id}_K$, again by functorial properties, $H_k(f^m)=\text{id}_{H_k(K)}$, so our expressions become $$\begin{align*} x &= \alpha_0^m x \\
y &= \alpha_{2n}^m y  \end{align*}$$ Because $\dim H_0(K)=\dim H_{2n}(K)=1$, there are non-zero $x,y$ such that these expressions hold. Dividing then gives $$\begin{align*} \alpha_0^m &= 1_{\mathbb{F}} \\
\alpha_{2n}^m &=1_{\mathbb{F}}\end{align*}$$ $\textbf{My question is about the next sentence}$. Because $m$ is odd, the only solution is $\alpha_0=1_{\mathbb{F}}$ and $\alpha_{2n}=1_{\mathbb{F}}$.
This then proves that $H_0(f)=\text{id}_{H_0(K)}$ and $H_{2n}(f)=\text{id}_{H_{2n}(K)}$. Thus, $$\begin{align*} \text{tr} H_0(f) &=\text{tr} \  \text{id}_{H_0(K)} =\dim H_0(K) \\ 
\text{tr} H_{2n}(f) &=\text{tr} \ \text{id}_{H_{2n}(K)} =\dim H_{2n}(K)\end{align*}$$ and $\text{tr}H_r(f)=0$ for $r\neq 0,2n$. Then, $$\begin{align*} \lambda(f) &= \sum_{r\geq 0 } (-1)^r \text{tr} H_r(f) \\
&= \sum_{r\geq 0} (-1)^r \dim H_r(K) \\
&=\chi (K)  \\
&=2 \\
&\neq 0 \end{align*}$$ And so, by Lefschetz fixed-simplex theorem, $f$ fixes a simplex in $K$.

My question is about my reasoning just after the bold text regarding the use of $m$ being odd. My thinking there comes from considering $\mathbb{R}=\mathbb{F}$. However, I don't think my argumentation holds up with $\mathbb{F}=\mathbb{C}$, since we are also ignoring the complex roots of unity. Is there a better way to argue this point whilst keeping the rest of the proof the same?

I don't actually know this simplicial version of the Lefschetz theorem, but shouldn't it be enough to conclude that $\lambda(f) \neq 0$ over some field of characterstic zero, e.g. $\mathbb{Q}$ or $\mathbb{R}$? Why make your life harder by using $\mathbb{C}$?

@diracdeltafunk I had thought the Lefschetz number potentially depended on the field. Is there a reason I can restrict attention to a particular one here?

It turns out that the Lefschetz number is independent of the choice of (char. 0) field by the universal coefficient theorem. But even if you don't know this theorem, note that the map $f$ either fixes a simplex or it does not -- this can't depend on a choice of field!

@diracdeltafunk Thank you! The point that the choice of field doesn't affect whether $f$ fixes a simplex is what I had missed. If you post this as an answer I shall accept it.

As diracdeltafunk pointed out in the comments, whether a simplicial map fixes a simplex or not does not depend on the coefficients used.
So, setting $\mathbb{F}=\mathbb{Q}$ is sufficient to show a fixed simplex exists. Clearly, over $\mathbb{Q}$, if $m$ is odd $\alpha^m=1$ holds if and only if $\alpha=1$. So, the proof goes through fine with this adjustment.
